# how to add simple className and fucntion return at the same time in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to add 2 classes to `NavLink`. One of them is simple word "interlocuter" and the second is "active-int" only when link is active

##### I tried this:

```
<NavLink
  to="some-path"
  className={`${moduleStyle["simple-text"]} ${({isActive}) => isActive ? : 'active-int' : ''}`}
>
  Link
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `NavLink` component's `className` prop takes only a string or a function. Use the function variant to return the stringified classnames you want to use.

```
<NavLink
  to="some-path"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    [
      moduleStyle["simple-text"],
      isActive ? : 'active-int' : null
    ]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(" ")
  }
>
  Link
</NavLink>
```

Comment: could you explain me why did you type ".filter(Boolean)"?

Comment: @alex It filters out falsey values, i.e. if `isActive` is false and `null` is returned in the array. `Boolean` is a constructor, the code is similar to `.filter(value => Boolean(value))`... but saves the anonymous callback function because we can pass `Boolean` directly as the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `activeClassName`, docs : https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string

```
<NavLink
  to="/somepath"
  activeClassName="active-int"
  className="interlocuter"
>
```